# Transporting data from one workbook to different tabs in another workbook depending on criteria

Tags: vba, excel

Currently, I'm trying to transport data from one worksheet in a workbook (i'll call this copying workbook) to different worksheets in another workbook (i'll call this pasting workbook) depending on the type of data.

For example, in the copying workbook, there will be a column for "type of reason". If the type of reason is "over", then some data (not all) in that row will be transported to the "over" tab in the pasting workbook. Same goes if the type of reason is "short". Then some data in the row for "short" will be transported to the "short" tab in the pasting workbook. There are 4 types of reasons in total so 4 different tabs/worksheets in the pasting workbook.

Right now, I'm trying to set the variables for my different workbooks and worksheets, but I keep getting an error message that they can't find the "walmart.xlsm" file. But that's the exact name of the file I'm using.

Here is what I have so far:

```
Sub filterbyCustomer() 'Excel VBA autofilter Walmart
Range("A:A").AutoFilter 1, "Walmart", xlFilterValues
End Sub

Sub SortByDate()
Dim rSortRange As Range
Dim ws As worksheet

Set ws = Sheets("data")
Set rSortRange = ws.Range("B2", "B14")
rSortRange.Sort Key1:=ws.Range("B2"), Order1:=xlAscending, _
           Header:=xlNo, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
           Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, _
           DataOption2:=xlSortNormal, DataOption3:=xlSortNormal
End Sub

Sub foo()
Dim wbk1 As Workbook
Dim wbk2 As Workbook
Dim worksheet1 As worksheet
Dim worksheet2 As worksheet

' Open both workbooks, and worksheets first:
Set wbk1 = Workbooks.Open("walmart.xlsm")
Set wbk2 = Workbooks.Open("dummy.xlsm")
Set worksheet1 = Worksheets.Add("data")
Set worksheet2 = Worksheets.Add("overage")

'Now, copy what you want from wbk1,worksheet1:
wbk1.Sheets("data").Range("A2").Copy
'Now, paste to wbk2,worksheet2:
wbk2.Sheets("overage").Range("A2").PasteSpecial

End Sub
```

If someone could let me know what I'm doing wrong, that'd be great. Also, I'm completely new to VBA, so I apologize if some of my questions seem "dumb". Thanks in advance everyone!

Comment: What have you tried so far? It would be easier for others to help you out if you could paste your code and explain what you are trying to do and what kind of error are you getting.

Comment: Id further the previous comment by saying "I know you didnt bother googling this b/c i have personally answered this question so many times it hurts."

Comment: sorry about that! Added to my post above

Comment: @DougCoats that was kinda rude man, you don't have to comment anything if it hurts you that much lol

Comment: Well it isnt rude for me to point out that you didnt seem to have researched based on a question with no code. This is why posts get down votes. Also, I would say your request/question is within the top ten topics for excel vba - meaning that its so present here there is no way you couldnt have ran into it (seeing in how the rules state one should have at least tried to research). Now on to your problem now that youve provided code - see answer.

Answer (score 0):

you dont fully qualify what workbook you are trying to open.

```
 Set wbk1 = Workbooks.Open("walmart.xlsm")
```

doesnt tell the compiler what workbook it is or more importantly WHERE it is. The compiler doesnt assume directories/UNC paths, it has to be provided.